# What is the maximum number of cycles there can be in a graph with $x$ edges

Tags: graph-theory

Given a graph with $x$ edges and some number of vertices, what is the maximum number of cycles such a graph could possibly have?

Here is an example of what I mean:

Say you have 5 edges, then the maximum number of cycles would be 3 as in the following graph:

Vertices: {a,b,c,d} Edges: {(a,b),(b,c),(c,d),(d,a),(b,d)}

The 3 cycles are abd bcd and abcd. Also, I am thinking of a cycle as a subgraph so abd and dab are the same. I would like to know what the most possible number of cycles is for a graph with x edges.

Comment: Did you forget to mention "Hamiltonian"?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: The graphs with $x$ vertices include the Hamiltonian ones with $x$ vertices.

Comment: @AlexM. Apparently, I was misunderstanding a couple of definitions: I thought cycles were just closed paths, so I suggested he was just looking for Hamiltonian paths. Thinking about it, that too was not exactly the question. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

There is a proof for large enough $x$, a graph with $x$ edges has at most $1.443^x$ cycles.

*Arman, Andrii; Tsaturian, Sergei*, [**The maximum number of cycles in a graph with fixed number of edges**](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v26i4p42), Electron. J. Comb. 26, No. 4, Research Paper P4.42, 16 p. (2019). [ZBL1428.05147](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1428.05147).

Answer (score -1):

The maximum number of cycles is infinity (if you allow cycles that repeat edges; and if you have at least 1 cycle).

Comment: I dont think the maximum number of cycles in a graph with a set number of edges can be infinite. This is the definition I am using for cycle which can be found by google "cycle graph theory"

Comment: In graph theory, a cycle graph or circular graph is a graph that consists of a single cycle, or in other words, some number of vertices connected in a closed chain. The cycle graph with n vertices is called Cn.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, a cycle is a type subgraph so you cant have an infinite number of them.